# Shared folder not visible for existing users in Jupyterhub UI

Tags: jupyter, jupyterhub

I have installed jupyterhub in my servers and I have created multiple users and everything works fine. The login page in jupyterhub lands in `/home` directory. However I want to create a shared folder where users can share their notebooks, files with other users. I have created a group for users and a shared folder with permissions in `/opt/shared`. I want this directory to be visible in jupyterhub landing page.

I initially tried changing the `c.Spawner.notebook_dir` to `/opt` but this will allow all users to see the files created by other users as well and I don't want that to happen. To be more clear consider user A who creates 2 files `1.py` and `2.py`. Initially other users should not know what files user A has created and is working but if A wants to share `2.py` with other users he can copy it to shared folder.

There is a similar method which is explained [here](https://tljh.jupyter.org/en/latest/howto/content/share-data.html#option-2-create-a-read-only-shared-folder-for-data) suggesting to create a symbolic link but that is not working. The link actually says to login as a new user but how do I make it available to existing users. I can only login but I don't see shared folder in UI.
Can someone help me how to achieve this. BTW my config file is located at `/opt/jupyterhub_config.py`